# save data to json with knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js. 
What I want to do is for teachers to create questions and save these to a json file which will be later user in another app to display questions at randon. The last part works. If I have a json file with data, the app loads the data.
I would like several questions to be added to the json file.
So, I really do not quite understand how to use knockout. 
Here is the code I used and of course it does not work.

The html is:

```
<form id="addQuestion" data-bind="submit: save">
<div>
<label for="question">Enter question text here:</label>
<input id="question" name="question" type="text" data-bind="value: question"/><br>
<label for="answer1">Enter answer 1 or distractor here: </label>
<input id="answer1" name="answer1" type="text" data-bind="value: answer1'"/><br>
<label for="answer">Enter answer 2 or distractor here: </label>
<input id="answer2" name="answer2" type="text" data-bind="value: answer2"/> <br>
<label for="answer">Enter answer 3 or distractor here: </label>
<input id="answer3" name="answer3" type="text"  data-bind="value: answer3"/> <br>
<label for="`question">Enter answer 4 or distractor here: </label>
<input id="answer4" name="answer4" type="text"  data-bind="value: answer4"/> <br>  
<label for="correctAnswer">Enter correct answer number here: </label>
<input id="correctAnswer" name="correctAnswer" type="text"   data-bind="value: correctAnswer"/>    <br> 
<label for="image">Enter the image name: </label>
<input id="image" name="image" type="text"  data-bind="value: image"> <br>
<label for="feedbackInfo">Enter feedback info here: </label>
<input id="feedbackInfo" name="feedbackInfo" type="text"  data-bind="value: feedbackInfo"> <br>                  
<button type="button" data-bind="click: save">Submit</button> 
</div>
</form>`<form id="addQuestion" data-bind="submit: save">
```

And the code is:

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.question = ko.observable();
    self.answer1 = ko.observable();
    self.answer2 = ko.observable();
    self.answer3 = ko.observable();
    self.answer4 = ko.observable();
    self.correctAnswer = ko.observable();
    self.image = ko.observable();
    self.feedbackInfo = ko.observable();
        // send data for json file
    self.save = function(){
        $.ajax('libs/data', {
            data: ko.toJSON({ 
                question: self.question,  
                answer1: self.answer1, 
                answer2: self.answer2,
                answer3: self.answer3,
                answer4: self.answer4,
                correctAnswer: self.correctAnswer,
                image: self.image,
                feedbackInfo: self.feedbackInfo                 
                }),
            type:POST,
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(result){alert(result)}
        });
    };

};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Are you seeing the success message when clicking Save button?

Comment: You are missing URL in $.ajax.

Comment: Dnyanesh is right. It looks like you're trying to use $.ajax to post directly into the data file. You need to post to a server-side script (PHP or Python), which will do the work of writing the data to the file.

Comment: OK. I did add the php. I am getting data in but it is in the wrong format. I think I need to do things differently when questions are all added in the form and then sent to json.